# Convert number in money format

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have asked this question several times, but still can't find an accurate solution for it.
I have a value in string, now i want to convert it into money format. For example If a=1000 then the result will be 1,000 if a=10000 then it will become 10,000 and so on in vb.net, I tried this(below), but it did not work, It shows an error

```
dim no as integer =1200
dim a as string= no.ToString("C")

Error: Conversion from string "C" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Comment: You said: " I have a value in string now i want convert it into money format" but you have value in integer and you are converting it into string. So I can't see what is the problem.

Comment: In order to use the "C" formatter you have to specify the culture you want to convert to. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString

Comment: It is works just fine. Can you tell exactly which line it throws an exception at?

Comment: @Nanhydrin: Would you please re-read that reference yourself. Culture is NOT required.

Comment: My bad, I see that it should just use the current culture.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this...

```
dim a as string= no.ToString("#,##0")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am used to using string.Format

```
dim no as integer =1200
dim a as string = string.Format("{0:C}",no)
```

hope it will help